# Formatting log does not work with Intellij community edition and spring boot

Tags: java, logging, intellij-idea, log4j

How to force Intellij Community edition to correctly format logs. Currently it looks like that:[image]

but in paid version it looks like that:
[image]

Comment: I would imagine the answer is "buy the paid version".

Comment: good deal € 499.00 /1st year for formatting logs